# PyQt5 : Call function from One class to another Class?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, python-module

I am new to Python and PyQt5.

Create two python files. First One contains a data for screen Geometry. And the next file I create a simple window with the data of first file. **Works Fine**.  But I am not satisfied, because I think this is not a proper way or Pythonic way.  So I seek your attention, to improve it.

> First File

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

class Mylayout(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.myscreen()

    def myscreen(self):
        global screen_width
        global screen_height
        global startpoint_x
        global startpoint_y

        screen_width  = 1000
        screen_height = 500

        resolution_width = QDesktopWidget().screenGeometry().width()
        resolution_height= QDesktopWidget().screenGeometry().height()

        if resolution_width > screen_width:
            startpoint_x = round((resolution_width - screen_width)/2)

        else:
            startpoint_x = 0


        if resolution_height > screen_height:
            startpoint_y = round((resolution_height - screen_height)/2)
        else:
            startpoint_y = 30

        return startpoint_x,startpoint_y,screen_width,screen_height

def main():
    myapp = QApplication(sys.argv)
    mywindow = Mylayout()
    mywindow.setGeometry(startpoint_x,startpoint_y,screen_width,screen_height)
    mywindow.show()
    sys.exit(myapp.exec_())

if __name__ =="__main__":
    main()
```

> Second File

```
from firstfile import *

class example(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        x = Mylayout()
        y = x.myscreen()
        xpoint = (y[0])
        ypoint = (y[1])
        width  = (y[2])
        height = (y[3])

        self.setGeometry(xpoint, ypoint, width, height)

def main():
    myapp = QApplication(sys.argv)
    mywindow = example()
    mywindow.show()
    sys.exit(myapp.exec_())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: If firstfile should only provide a function for setting up the widget's geometry, why not just make it a simple function with the widget as argument. If there's more than that, you might be better off creating a base class and subclassing that. If you really want two different widgets, it might be good as is. Can't really say since it's unclear what you're actually trying to achieve.

Comment: In second file,I want to create a simple window with first file data. I don't know how? With my knowledge develop this. I need a proper /simple way to create . @jeronimo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

I am also new. So somebody suggest, this way is correct or wrong :

> First File

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

class Mylayout(QWidget):
    def __init__(self,mywidget):
        self.mywindow = mywidget
        self.myscreen()

    def myscreen(self):
        screen_width  = 1000
        screen_height = 500

        resolution_width = QDesktopWidget().screenGeometry().width()
        resolution_height= QDesktopWidget().screenGeometry().height()

        if resolution_width > screen_width:
            startpoint_x = round((resolution_width - screen_width)/2)
        else:
            startpoint_x = 0

        if resolution_height > screen_height:
            startpoint_y = round((resolution_height - screen_height)/2)
        else:
            startpoint_y = 30

        return startpoint_x,startpoint_y,screen_width,screen_height
```

> Second File

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from firstfile import *

class example(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.myframe = QMainWindow(self)
        self.getsize = Mylayout(self.myframe)
        xpoint,ypoint,width,height = self.getsize.myscreen()
        self.setGeometry(xpoint, ypoint, width, height)

def main():
    myapp = QApplication(sys.argv)
    mywindow = example()
    mywindow.show()
    sys.exit(myapp.exec_())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```